# Tree-view, returned with js function, doesn't keep filters, when I click back in browser from form-view to the tree-view

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

Tree view is linked with js button. When I click into the button - tree view opens and I can select filters. When I click into some record - opens the form-view. But when I click 'back' in browser - opens previous tree view but filters disappear. How can I keep these filters when I click 'back' in browser? Because normally, without js, filters are stable between tree-view and form-view. Here is my function which returns tree view:

```
     show_lines: function() {
      self = this;
      rpc.query({
       model: 'sale.order',
       method: 'getViewIdForJs',
       args: [[]],
       }).then(function (res) {
       return self.do_action({
        type: "ir.actions.act_window",
        res_model: "sale.order",
        name:'Show lines',
        view_type : 'list,form',
        views: [[res[0],'list'],[false,'form']],
        view_mode : 'tree,form',
    });
  });
}
```